# Deleted Ubuntu Partion, stuck on grub2

Tags: dual-boot

I deleted my Ubuntu partition, and tried to boot a recovery drive, but I just get grub. Grub also says "unknown filesystem" for all partitions. Is there a way to bypass grub?

I'm using Windows 8.1, Grub 2 and a UEFI Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this. I fixed the problem by

1. inserting a Boot Repair Utility live USB I made beforehand (but can be made from another device). This works beautifully even if you want to get rid of Ubuntu later. A note from Ubuntu:

*> It is recommended to install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via UnetBootin or LiliUSB or Universal USB Installer). Do not burn it on a DVD if your computer has Windows8 pre-installed, or if your boot is in EFI mode.*

2. Forced the system to choose boot device (pressed F12 immediately once I turned the system on).
3. Let the Boot repair Utility do its thing.

Afterwards It still gave me the option to choose Ubuntu (I chose the Windows sda loader instead). In my case I replaced Ubuntu with Fedora on my Scientific machine and kept Ubuntu on my personal machine. I never saw the choice to choose the deleted partition again once I installed a new Linux Distro on the hard drive.
If you don't want another distro, once you get back to the Disk Manager in Windows, you can then expand the partition. But then go to eightforums.com to find the Windows side of things.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10871917#post10871917

If that fails start here:

http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/48737-how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-without-recovery-partition-usb-boo.html

You can search in this forum for the windows side of things. Good luck!